# CriteriaBuilder Equals two Strings

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to create a predicate that compares two strings, but for some reason its breaking...

```
predicates.add(builder.equal(rootBoat.get("boatProfile"), boatFilter.getBoatProfile()));
```

In the database there's a column called boat_profile that can be two values, `"RECURRENT" or "EVENTUAL"`. So I want to bring only boats that corresponds to eventual or recurrent, depending on the parameter passed by the user... My goal in query native is something like: "...where b.boat_profile = 'filter_boat_profile'..."

There's an important detail: the BoatProfile field from `rootBoat.get("boatProfile")` corresponds to an enum:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private BoatProfile boatProfile;
```

BoatProfile:

```
public enum BoatProfile {
    RECURRENT,
    EVENTUAL
}
```

Also, I keep getting this error:

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter
> value [RECURRENT] did not match expected type
> [br.com.easymarine.model.boat.Boat (n/a)]

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was happening, in my `boatFilter.getBoatProfile()`, I set this attr as String, but since the original attr is an enum, all I needed to do was also set this guy as the same enum class...